# hook_theme_registry_alter caches

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

this function caches the output, so it doesnt work if I want to change dynamically between two template files. For example user-profile.tpl.php and user-profile-project.tpl.php

Code:

```
function hook_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $tmp1 = arg(0);
  $tmp2 = arg(1);
  $tmp3 = arg(2);

  if ($tmp1 == "user" && is_numeric($tmp2) && !$tmp3) {
    $user = user_load($tmp2);
    $roles = $user->roles;
    if (in_array('project', $roles)) {
     $theme_registry['user_profile']['template'] = 'user-profile-project';
    }
  }
}
```

So how can I do this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `hook_user_profile_preprocess()` and add your template suggestion as last entry of `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']`. Instead of using `arg()` as you are doing, use [`menu_get_object('user', 1)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7).

`hook_theme_registry_alter()` is not good because:

- Drupal caches what it gets from `hook_theme_registry_alter()`

  ```
    // _theme_registry_build()
    if ($cached = cache_get('theme_registry:build:modules')) {
      $cache = $cached->data;
    }
  ```
- It is never invoked for each page request Drupal gets; so you could not for which user the user profile is.

Then, the Drupal way would probably be to check the user has a specific permission rather than a specific role.

```
if ($account = menu_get_object('user', 1) && user_access('your permission', $account)) {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'your template suggestion';
}
```